# Can not login via nodejs with https.get and auth parameter to page on another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

*Hi I´m trying to figure out how to login to a website with node js.
Even if I get back a 200 OK , I'm NOT logged in to the page.
The loggin is normally via form on the page, but for complex functionality it should work via nodes.
Here is my actual code, is there something wrong with the code ?*

```
var express = require('express'),
request = require("request"),
https = require('https'),
http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(app.router);
});





var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer("usernameString:passwordString");
var options = require('url').parse( "https://example.com/path" );


options.rejectUnauthorized =false;
options.host="example.com"; 
options.path="https://example.com/usr/login"; 
options.defaultEncoding = 'utf8';
options.headers= { 'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   "Proxy-Authorization": auth,
                    host: "example.com",'accept-encoding': '*' 
                 };

options.agent = new https.Agent( options );



var req = https.get(  options, function(res) {
console.log(res.statusCode); //200 but not logged in ?!?
 });
```

UPDATE:

If I test the login with an AJAX request, everything works fine but I need NODE JS:

Here the JavaScript code with ajax:

```
$.ajax{( 
type: get,
…
…
data: "LoginForm[username]=usernameString&LoginForm[password]=passwordString"

…)};
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases authenticating service will return a cookie which you have to include in every following requests so that the remote service recognize you ...

Comment: maybe the cookie can not be set on localhost:3000 ?

Comment: How to include the cookie form res.headers['set-cookie'] ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, proxy authentication works the same as basic authentication, in that a client is never really *logged in* (by means of a session being held by the server), but just sends the authentication headers along with every request.

So try sending the `Proxy-Authorization` header along for every request you make.

**EDIT**: okay so perhaps you don't need to use proxy authentication at all. I also noticed that your `options.path` is incorrect: it should only contain the path name, not a full URL.

Try this:

```
options.path = "/usr/login?LoginForm[username]=usernameString&LoginForm[password]=passwordString";
```

Comment: OK, thank you! How to notice if the loggin was successfull ? I always get 200 OK I think it´s not logged in because the html code from  response "res" is the content of the not logged in page, maybe it´s something concerning the loginproperties, seen in the update!

Comment: @user3178233 see my edit. It's unclear whether you actually need proxy authentication at all, since the AJAX request you're posting looks like a normal HTTP GET request.